# Christian sci-fi/fantasy book series about teenagers who are put into cryosleep before a nuclear war

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, post-apocalyptic, christian

It's a Christian-inspired series about teenagers who are put into cryosleep before a nuclear war.

The first book starts with a teenage boy waking up and not being able to recognize his own father, due to mutation.  He then assembles the other frozen teens and meets a Jesus stand-in character.  The Jesus archetype sends them on a quest to unite different parts of the world for a final Revelations-style Armageddon.

Each book after is about convincing a different faction: Atlanteans, knights, cavemen, winged hawk-like people (actually just people with glider wings), and magicians.

Comment: In roughly which year/s did you read these books and when do you think they might've been published? Also, do you recall how many books there were in the series?

Answer (score 6):

Could this be the [*Seven Sleeper Series*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/42182-the-seven-sleepers) by Gilbert L. Morris, starting with [*Flight of the Eagles*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/450371.Flight_of_the_Eagles)?

> Fourteen-year-old Joshua Adams wakes from a fifty-year sleep to find
> that he has escaped nuclear war—and that the genetically altered races
> of Earth now hail his awakening as the first fulfillment of an ancient
> prophecy.
>
> For of old it was sung that the Seven Sleepers would awaken to unite
> their strength with Goél and join in battle against the wicked priests
> of the Sanhedrin. But the choice of Josh and each member of the quest
> is a dangerous one. He must survive not only the peril of the
> Sanhedrin but the doubt that threatens his faith and, ultimately, his
> commitment to Goél, his spiritual champion.
>
> [image]

The following books in the series deal with the [Lost City of Atlantis](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/359677.The_Gates_of_Neptune), [cave people](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/859023.The_Caves_That_Time_Forgot), [winged hawk-people](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/359663.Winged_Raiders_of_the_Desert), etc etc

Comment: definitely this, I remember reading these as a kid